# How to conditionally put different running footer using only css?

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I want to add a footer in all the pdf pages generated from HTML when printed, but only for the first page, I want to add a section below the common footer. I have to do it using only HTML and CSS.

```
<head>
 <style>
      .footerLeft {
        position: running(footerLeft);
      }
      @page {
        margin-bottom: 40%;
        margin-top: 5%;
        @bottom-left {
          content: element(footerLeft);
        }
      }
 </style> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="footerLeft">
     ...content
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to add another **div** below the *"footerLeft"* div class only for the first page. I am using this thymeleaf for the final compilation, would want to know if there is any property that can help me achieve this apart from plain HTML & CSS. Can somebody please help me with this problem?